# Matlab - Why am I getting this error

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimension

I have typed the following in `matlab`:

```
>> I=imread('23X41.jpg');
>> fun = @(x) sum(x(:).^2)/sum(x(:)).^2; 
>> en= nlfilter(I,[4 4],fun);
```

And, got the following error?

```
??? Error using ==> plus
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> nlfilter at 52
aa = mkconstarray(class(a), padval, size(a)+nhood-1);
```

Why am I getting this error especially that I'm sliding a `4x4` window on a `23x41` image? Why are the matrix dimensions mentioned here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your image is 2D and not a color image which is a 3D array.